# What is the difference between trunk and branch in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

So, I tried to search for an answer but all I find is different schemes of version control but not the difference.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you are coming from svn.... trunk would be *just another  branch*... just like any other that you might create. What is generally called trunk in svn is called *master* on git, but actually, that's a convention because there is no mandate to have a master branch on a repo, it's just that most repos do have it.... and you might have a branch called trunk in git, if so you like.

Answer (score 5):

Git does not have a "trunk" (though you can pretend that any particular branch is your "trunk" if you like).

For that matter, in one sense, Git doesn't have branches either.  It really all depends on how you define *branch*.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  Of course, if we define the word *branch* in a more useful way, Git *does* have branches.  They are just very different from SVN branches.

Interestingly, SVN itself also doesn't have branches, in some sense.  Here is a quote from the [Red Bean book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html):

> You should remember two important lessons from this section. First, Subversion has no internal concept of a branch—it knows only how to make copies. When you copy a directory, the resultant directory is only a “branch” because you attach that meaning to it. You may think of the directory differently, or treat it differently, but to Subversion it's just an ordinary directory that happens to carry some extra historical information.

As for Git, the important thing to remember is that Git is all about *commits*.  The commit is a major [leitmotif](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/leitmotif) of Git.  Every commit carries a full snapshot of your source code, plus some metadata: information *about* the commit.  Every commit has a unique hash ID,<sup>1</sup> reserved to *that* commit and *only that commit*.  For instance, [`b697d92f56511e804b8ba20ccbe7bdc85dc66810`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b697d92f56511e804b8ba20ccbe7bdc85dc66810) is the commit that is Git 2.22 in any clone of the Git repository for Git itself.  No other commit anywhere will have *that* hash ID.<sup>2</sup>

Because each commit has a unique hash ID, we—or at least Git—can talk about or find the commit given just the hash ID.  So in general, each commit stores, in its metadata, the hash ID of some other *earlier* commit.  Specifically, the earlier commit that we—or Git—care about most is the hash ID of the immediate *parent* of the commit: the one that comes *right before* the commit.

Note that when we make a *new* commit, we **know** *exactly which commit* should come before the new commit we're making now.  That's because we make a *new* commit by checking out, with `git checkout`, some existing commit.  Then we work on that commit and do our `git add` commands and run `git commit`.  The new commit should have, as its parent, the hash ID of the commit we checked out.

Let's take a quick look at how this works.  But commit hash IDs are big and ugly and impossible for mere humans to work with (except via cut and paste), so let's use single uppercase letters to stand in for these commits.  Let's take a simple, tiny repository with three commits in it, and call them `A`, `B`, and `C` as we made them in that order.  Each commit stores the hash ID of its parent, which makes up a backwards-pointing chain of commits:

```
A <-B <-C
```

That is, commit `C` says *my parent is `B`*, and `B` says *my parent is `A`*.  `A` has no parents—it can't, it was the first commit.  The technical term for this is that `A` is a *root commit*, and you'll see `[root commit]` printed by Git when you make the very first commit in a new repository.<sup>3</sup>

If we check out commit `C`, do some work on it, and then run `git commit`, Git will:

- package up our updated files to go into the new snapshot;
- collect our metadata: name and email address, the date-and-time of this new commit, and so on, and our log message to remind us later *why* we made this new commit;
- put the hash ID of commit `C` in as this new commit's parent into the metadata too; and
- write out a new commit, obtaining a new and unique big ugly hash ID.

Because new commit `D`'s parent is `C`, this automatically extends the chain:

```
A <-B <-C <-D
```

Of course, `D` gets a commit hash ID, which is big and ugly and unique to `D` and there is no way *we* could ever remember it.  But we don't need to remember it: that's what the *computer* is for.  Let's have the *computer* remember it, by storing the actual hash ID in some name.

That name is—usually—a *branch name* like `master`.  That is, before we make `D`, the picture really looks like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

The name `master` remembers the actual hash ID of commit `C`.  We run `git checkout master` and Git uses the *name* to find the ID, and the ID to find the commit, which gets us the content into our work-tree so that we can work on it.<sup>4</sup>

We do our work and run `git add` and `git commit` and make new commit `D`.  The *last* step of `git commit` is that Git writes `D`'s actual hash ID—whatever it is—into the name `master`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

`master` no longer remembers `C`, but rather `D`; but that's OK, because *`D`* remembers `C`.  At one point earlier, `master` remembered `A`; then it remembered `B`, which remembered `A`; then it remembered `C`.  Now it remembers `D`.

To create a *new* branch in Git, you just tell it to make a new name, **pointing to some existing commit**, like this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, feature
```

The trick now is to have Git remember which *branch name* to update when you run `git commit`, and that's where the special name `HEAD`, in all capital letters, comes in.  When you run `git checkout master`, Git attaches the name `HEAD` to the name `master`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD), feature
```

When you run `git checkout feature`, Git attaches `HEAD` to `feature` instead:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, feature (HEAD)
```

*Both* checkout commands extract commit `D`, which is where all your files are stored.  And both *branches* have all four commits, at this point—but if you're on `feature` and make a new commit now, that new commit gets a new big ugly hash ID, which we'll call `E`.  The new commit has `D` as its parent, and as the last step of `git commit`, Git writes `E`'s hash ID into `feature` because that's where `HEAD` is attached:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

If we now run `git checkout master`, Git puts commit `D` back into our work-tree and attaches `HEAD` to `master`.  If we now make another new commit, the new commit's parent is `D` again, and `master` gets updated this time:

```
           F   <-- master (HEAD)
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           E   <-- feature
```

These commits—these backwards-looking chains—form a *graph*, technically a Directed Acyclic Graph.  Branch names like `master` and `feature` are, in effect, just *labels* pointing to particular nodes within the graph.  When you say "branch feature", be careful about whether you mean the *name* `feature`, or commit `E`, or commits `E`+`D`+`C`+`B`+`A`, or whatever.

#### Summary

In Git, a *branch name* is just a label pointing to one specific commit.  The *branch itself* is found by starting at that commit and working backwards through the graph.  The graph is composed of the commits and their parent linkages.

In SVN, as the Red Bean book says, a branch is a copy of a directory (plus some metadata).  That's not true for Git—the word *branch* is ambiguous, and sometimes means the *name*, the short label holding a commit hash ID, and sometimes means *some subset of the overall commit graph as found by starting with the hash ID in the name*.  When by "branch" we mean "some set of commits", it's those *commits*, not some directory.

---

<sup>1</sup>These hash IDs are actually cryptographic checksums of the commit data (the snapshot and metadata).  Because of this, no commit can ever be changed.  If you actually take the raw commit data—which you can via `git cat-file -p`; try `git cat-file -p HEAD` some time—and make some change to it and store it back into Git, what you get is a *new and different commit* with its own new, unique hash ID.  You can think of Git as an append-only database containing commits.  That's not strictly true, but it's a good first approximation.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, this just means no Git-repository-of-Git can re-use that hash ID.  Your own project, if it is not the source for Git and is never connected to a Git repository for Git, *could* use that hash ID.  Chances are very good that it never will: each commit you make has only a 1 out of 2<sup>160</sup> chance to us *that* hash ID.  2<sup>160</sup> is a very big number: 1,461,501,637,330,902,918,203,684,832,716,283,019,655,932,542,976, or about one and a half quindecillion in the [short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers).

<sup>3</sup>A *branch name* has to point to some existing commit.  This gives rise to a problem: in a new and totally-empty repository, there are no commits, so there can be no branches.  It's the act of making the first commit—the root commit of the new repository—that creates the initial branch name, usually `master`.  You can make new root commits later, by using `git checkout --orphan` or by using `git fetch` to another Git repository that has an unrelated history, but a typical Git repository tends to have only *one* root commit.  That one root commit is on *every* branch!

<sup>4</sup>Because of the cryptographic checksum hash ID, every commit is frozen for all time.  But this is also true of the snapshot that each commit saves.  The files "inside" a commit—which are technically just more objects in the Git object database—are *also* frozen for all time, and are kept in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed format.  Because they're read-only, they can be *shared* across different commits, which saves a lot of space: you might have a project with 4000 files, and you change 2 and make a new commit.  Git re-saves *every* file in the new commit, but 3998 of them are actually just re-using the previous snapshot: there are only 2 new snapshots.

This is great for archival, but useless for doing actual work.  These files are all in this freeze-dried Git-only form, and your computer needs its files in their normal everyday form.  So Git has to unpackage the freeze-dried files, rehydrating them.  Those rehydrated copies go into your *work-tree*, where you can see and work on them.  You're never working directly on the in-Git copies.

This process of freeze-drying files and rehydrating them uses an in-between area that Git sometimes calls the *staging area*, or sometimes calls the *index*.  These two words are terms for the same thing.  It's important to realize that the index / staging area has copies of *every* file from the current commit, and that Git makes new commits *from* the index / staging-area rather than from the work-tree, but we won't go any further into that here.